# Create new dataframe from mean calculation according to labels

Tags: r

From a data input frame like this:

```
dframe <- structure(list(com = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("col1", 
"em"), class = "factor"), com_num = c(3.1, 2.1, 2.1, 4.1), stock1 = c(3.1, 
0, 2.1, 4.1), aim = c(3.1, 2.1, 0, 4.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

How is it possible to create a output like this:

```
data.frame (value = c("col1, em"), stock1 = c(2.6, 2.05), aim = c(1.55, 3.1))
```

The conditions are:
For every column stock1 and aim we use the label of com column and calculate the mean value for every label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dplyr and summarise the target variables after grouping the data.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_2 <- dframe %>% 
    group_by(com) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(stock1, aim), mean)

df_2
```

Comment: Which library are you use?

Comment: library(tidyverse)